# Making a jar of an android project to use in another android project?

Tags: android

I made an android project using eclipse. It looks like:

```
src/
   ActivityMain.java
   lib/
      Square.java
      Circle.java
```

I want to export only the /lib package really as a jar (don't want to include stuff at the top level like ActivityMain.java). Are there any special rules I need to be aware of before jar-ing this for use in another android project, or I should be all set?

Thanks

Comment: hey.. i m also trying to make a lib like yours. how can we create a jar from a android project. im a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that `Square` and `Circle` cannot reference resources (at least not via `R.` syntax), and that JARs cannot package resources, manifest entries, etc. If all you are trying to JAR up is pure Java code (perhaps using Android APIs), then you should be fine.