# Android project as Jar Library

Tags: android

I am currently working on a Android Project where we are expected to merge our App with 2 more apps from vendors who wouldn't be sharing their code.So just wanted to know Is there any way we could just include there Source code as JAR Files in our project and then include their resources and point to them(I did do it using getResources().getIdentifier("splash", "layout", getPackageName()) But Its still not working ?? I think I have tried all possible methods so hoping you guys could help me with this.

Comment: I Am sorry If am creating Multiple threads but seriously need to get a  quick response.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To quote CommonsWare from  [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519975/making-a-jar-of-an-android-project-to-use-in-another-android-project)

> Bear in mind that your packaged classes cannot reference resources (at
>   least not via R. syntax), and that JARs cannot package resources,
>   manifest entries, etc. If all you are trying to JAR up is pure Java
>   code (perhaps using Android APIs), then you should be fine.

Basically, you can only use JARs that contain pure java as libraries in your app, not entire other projects.

Comment: Thanks for the response but there should be some way out of this. We been stuck here for long now.

Comment: Sadly there isn't. Which is a good thing to be honest, otherwise you could just include any other app in yours and blatantly rip their code / resources.

Comment: But it does work on the IOS Framework. So I feel there should be something on the Android side too.

Comment: This is coming in a future ADT update, possibly ADT 17. I think it was supposed to be in ADT 16 but got pushed back.

Answer (score 0):

The Activities can be compiled into a jar and added to the main Android project and we need to add their project's resources into your Project. The only we could make it work is using the  `getResources().getIdentifier("splash", "layout", getPackageName())`. Even the Widgets like `TextView`, `Button` and all those should be referred to using the `getResources()` method. Like, for example, If you want to perform a action on particular button then we need to identify them by `getResources().getIdentifier("Button" /*id in the XML File*/, "id"/*type*/, getPackageName())`.

One more thing: you need to specify all the Activities in your Main Android Project's `AndroidManifest.xml` file with their package name. I hope this solves something.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support faster build times, the r16 tools are creating their own jar files inside of Android Library Projects.  You can use this feature to solve this issue.  If a vendor would like to release their Android Library Project but without source code, they can make a copy of that Android Library Project that contains everything except for the source code tree.  Next, include the jar file from the original Android Library Porject (the one that the r16 tools built.)  This will allow you to have a component you can distribute that does not require source code.  The consumer of this new Android Library Project will need to manually add any necessary meta data to their own project's AndroidManifest.xml file as needed (Activities, Providers, Permissions, etc).