# Creating jar file for SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-sliding

Can anyone help me to create jar file of sliding menu project. https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu ? If i add the jar file which is created then im getting exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.slidingmenu.lib.R$styleable. I dont want to add entire project as dependent but need to add the jar.

Comment: you can't ... even if compiled code is in the jar you still need resources as another project

Answer (score 5):

Projects that use resources of their own (layouts, manifest entries etc) cannot be converted into a jar successfully. This is the reason it is recommended that you use it as an Android library project. Unless a project is pure java code with no resources of it's own, converting it into jar is not gonna be successful.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520113/1369222